# In a hybrid asp.net mvc/webforms app, why does my redirect have a MIME of 'text/plain'?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

For one reason or another, I have a site where the logout is performed then the user is redirected to the landing site which is separate (the landing is hosted in Azure, the main is hosted elsewhere). In MVC, the logout action is using the following (vb) code:

```
Function LogOut() As ActionResult
    Session.Abandon()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    Return Redirect("~/")
End Function
```

And it does what it's supposed to do, but after this last update (tried to use some bits from the html5boilerplate - just some css, and some security headers), in Chrome only, there's a brief flash of this redirect code before the user is sent back to the landing site:

```
<html><head><title></title><script language="javascript">window.location = 'http://<site here>';</script></head><body></body></html>
```

In all other browsers (IE, FF, Safari), the user doesn't see anything out of the ordinary - but Chrome users see the html code in the raw. Looking at Chrome's log (preserved over the action), I see that the page in question is being served with `text/plain` rather than `text/html` and I'm rather puzzled as to the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was inadvertently setting `X-Content-Type-Options` to `nosniff`, and in Chrome - if the MIME isn't set then it wants to "sniff" by looking at the content. By explicitly disallowing it, the browser had no option but to use text/plain.

TL;DR - Make sure `X-Content-Type-Options` is not set.